# Can Vim determine whether or not it should prepend a semicolon at the end?

Tags: vim

I use the auto-pairs plugin which in works great but there are two additional settings that I want to have.

I want Vim to be able to distinguish between an array and an if-statement for example.

So when I type

```
int arr[] = {1, 2}; // Vim should be able to determine that it is an array and then prepend the semicolon at the end

if ( ... ) { } // Vim should be able to determine that the if-statement doesn't need a semicolon at the end
```

Is this possible with Vim?

Answer (score 2):

I suggested something fairly similar yesterday:

How about adding this in your ftplugin file:

```
function! CloseBracket()
        if getline('.') =~ '^struct\s\w\+\s'
                return "{}\<left>\<cr>\<c-o>O\<tab>"
        endif
        return "{};\<left>\<left>"
endfunction

inoremap { <C-R>=CloseBracket()<CR>
```

So when **{** is pressed in insert mode we insert the contents of a register , the following **=** then states we want to use the expression register which in this case is the **CloseBracket** function.

The function it self gets the current line, and runs some regex to see if the line is a struct definition, if so it does some fancy foot work as requested, otherwise it just closes the brackets and moves the cursor left.

I've not tested this with any plugins though.

Answer (score 1):

In [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets), I partly do so when the opening curly brackets is typed on the same line as a  `struct`, `class`, `union` or `enum` declaration.

It's done thanks to two things: first it permits to register a hook for each part of the pair, and then the hook I've registered by default does the analysis.

```
" in after/ftplugin/c/c_brackets.vim
" NB: that's how bracket mappings are defined for insert, normal and visual modes
:Brackets { } -default -visual=0 -insert=1
    \ -open=function('lh#cpp#brackets#curly_open')
    \ -clos=function('lh#cpp#brackets#curly_close')

" in autoload/lh/cpp/brackets.vim
function! lh#cpp#brackets#curly_open() abort
  let c = col('.') - 1
  let l = getline('.')
  let l = strpart(l, 0, c)
  let close =  l =~ 'struct\|class\|enum\|union' ? '};' : '}'
  if lh#brackets#usemarks()
    return '{!cursorhere!'.close.'!mark!'
  else
    return '{!cursorhere!'.close
  endif
endfunction
```

As you can see the analysis is quite simplistic. It could be enhanced.

Now, while your idea is sound for your example, it's actually quite complex to do so correctly. I see a few other situations that aren't easy to distinguish from Vim:

- N dimensions arrays (`int t[2][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4}};`)
- C++11 *unicorn* initialisation syntax (`std::complex<double> i{0,1};`)
- C++11 lambda definitions (`auto pred = [](int i){ return i < 42};`)
- C++11 direct lambda use (`auto it = std::find_if(beg, end, [](int i){ return i < 42});`)
- embedded artificial scopes

That's why I haven't invest time on extending this feature. It requires more than just regular expressions to analyse the current context.

PS: This can be easily overridden by calling `:Brackets` yourself in the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c_brackets.vim` where you define your own hook for `{`.

Answer (score 0):

This was previously requested, and rejected by the author of auto-pairs.

https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs/issues/69

The issue mentions another plug-in, [delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate), which apparently supports this feature, by setting [`b:delimitMate_eol_marker`](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/blob/2.7/doc/delimitMate.txt#L320), possibly per filetype. I haven't checked whether it fits your requirements (particularly skipping it after a block on an `if` or `while`.)

If that interests you, you might want to give that plug-in a try.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be feasible using [ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips). Create a snipped 
called *arr*. You would type even faster.

```
snippet arr "inserts an array" w
${1:int} arr[] = {${2:your values}};
endsnippet
```

Of course, you can change your placeholders as you want